# How to rename object key in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular8

I am getting an object like this:

[image]

> on web page it looking like this :

[image]

I want to remove "_" and it should look like this :

```
Is Supplier? (toggle)   Is Customer?  (toggle)   Is Cashbook AC?  (toggle) ,etc..
```

> .ts code

```
getCompanyConfig() {
        this.companiesService.companyConfig({page: -1}).subscribe(data => {
            this.companyToggleArr = data.items;
            console.log(this.companyToggleArr)           
        });
    }
```

> .html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="100px">
            <mat-grid-tile class="ml-1 mr-1" *ngFor="let companyToggle of companyToggleArr; let i = index">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                    <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">{{companyToggle.name}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="companyToggle.name" name="{{'name' + i}}"></mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways u can do it.

U can create [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes). specially designed to remove any '_' from string

U can use simple function which i don't recommend.

Pipe for u
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'companyName'
})
export class CompanyNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
    return value.replace('_', " ");
  }

}

// template
    <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">{{companyToggle.name | companyName }}</mat-label>
```

Comment: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded! error getting

Answer (score 0):

just use Array.map function to modify each name value:

```
this.companyToggleArr = data.items.map(companyToggle => {
 companyToggle.name = companyToggle.name.replace('_', ' ') + '?';

 return companyToggle;
})
```

and use CSS for your labels to capitalize the first letter:

```
.label {
    text-transform: capitalize; // capitalizes the first letter of each word in the selected text.
}
```

Comment: "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error getting

Comment: @aashu1807 - because of having ele after the name is causing the issue
can you try with this - companyToggle.name.replace('_', ' ') + '?'

Comment: @aashu1807 sorry made a mistake, already fixed, there was unnecessary  field name

Comment: @DmitrySobolevsky how can i pass these values as parameter to backend?

Comment: @DmitrySobolevsky after toggling on and off it hiding the label and giving "true" and "false"

Comment: @aashu1807 so your question was not cover all your requirements :)
in this case, you have to add additional field 'label' and use it for UI labels, but use field 'name' to store selected points in your form control

Answer (score 0):

create an auxiliar array with the labels

```
 labels:string[]
 this.companiesService.companyConfig({page: -1}).subscribe(data => {
        this.companyToggleArr = data.items;
        this.labels=data.items.map(x=>"Is "+x.name.split('_')[1]
    });
```

And use

```
 <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">{{labels[i]}}</mat-label>
```

Comment: for adding "?" i written this.labels=data.items.map(x=>"Is "+x.name.split('_')+"?"[1]) but not getting

Comment: @aashu1807, when I make split('_'), I create an array, e.g. for is_supplier: `['is','supplier']` this is the reason I get the second element of the array, I suppose you want to say `map(x=>("Is "+x.name.split('_')[1]+"?"))` I don't know if is neccesarry the parenthesis